# Why stack memory is lesser than heap?

Tags: java, memory-management, stack, heap-memory

I was going through this post [difference-between-stack-and-heap-java](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2013/01/difference-between-stack-and-heap-java.html) and It says

> *** size of stack memory is a lot lesser than the size of  heap memory in Java.

Why? What are the possible cases for that?

Comment: The Stack is the kitchen you do your work and the Heap is the store that you store in/ bring from the food and all the stuff to do the work! So which one should be bigger you think in case you work extremely fast?

Comment: The stack contains only primitive types (like int, float, ...)
and object references, but not the objects themselves.
All objects are on the heap.

Comment: For the record, "[a]ll objects are on the heap" is only true in Java but not in the JVM. In the JVM things are different. In the JVM objects can live on the stack, or in registers, or disappear altogether, at the will of the optimizer and JIT/HotSpot compiler.

Comment: @rootTraveller, look up what "stack" and "heap" memory are in general, not just for Java (or the JVM). This is easily findable on line, but to save you two minutes of searching, stack is the working memory of a method (function), holding the "stack frame", i.e., return location, argument values, and local variables. Heap is the overall memory for the program data, holding objects (mainly) and their attributes.